# Handling NULL in Sql server string concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, string-concatenation

I have the following SQL query

```
select s.comments + s.further_comments from dbo.samples s where id = 1234
```

However if s.comments or s.further_comments is NULL the whole string is returned NULL

How do I convert the NULL value to an empty string or at least only return the non NULL values in this string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use either [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933210%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) or [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for this.

```
SELECT ISNULL(s.comments, '') + ISNULL(s.further_comments, '')
SELECT COALESCE(s.comments, '') + COALESCE(s.further_comments, '')
```

[ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

```
Replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.
```

[COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

```
Returns the first nonnull expression among its arguments.
```

Note that there *are* [some differences](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx) between the two methods but for all intents and purposes, they most likely don't apply to your situation.

> 1. ISNULL(NULL, NULL) -- is int
> 2. COALESCE(NULL, NULL) -- Will throw an error
> 3. COALESCE(CAST(NULL as int), NULL) -- it valid and returns int
> 4. ISNULL takes only 2 parameters whereas COALESCE takes variable number of parameters
> 5. COALESCE is based on the ANSI SQL standard whereas ISNULL is a proprietary TSQL function

Comment: Also useful if you need to join on columns that are nullable.